# How to change default line length for black or flake8 in a poetry virtual environment?

Tags: flake8, python-poetry, python-black

I have loaded black and flake8 into a poetry virtual environment. I'd like to change the default line length in black or flake8 so they agree. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: what have you tried so far? the configuration methodology for the tools doesn't change because you're using poetry

Answer (score 5):

Add a file `.flake8` with the following :

```
[flake8]
max-line-length = 120
```

You can also do the same using a `setup.cfg` file.

Answer (score 2):

You can use  [pyproject-flake8](https://pypi.org/project/pyproject-flake8/)   ,  a monkey patching wrapper to connect flake8 with pyproject.toml configuration.

or use [FlakeHeaven](https://github.com/flakeheaven/flakeheaven) : This project is a fork of FlakeHell.

> FlakeHell and other forks of it such as flakehell/flakehell are no
> longer maintained and do not work with Flake8 4.0.x.

Answer (score 1):

flake8 doesnt natively support `pyproject.toml` file yet. You can install Flake8-pyproject to add this functionality.

`pip install Flake8-pyproject`

Then you can simply use the `pyproject.toml to change flake8 settings like below:

```
[tool.flake8]
max-line-length = 120
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it good idea with

```
[tool.flake8]
max-line-length = 88
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? (It looks a _lot_ like the top-voted post!) **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score -1):

Modern Python projects that use `pyproject.toml` can do the following:

```ini
# We hate arbitrary line lengths
[tool.black]
line-length = 999
```

No additional files needed.

`pyproject.toml` should be the default for all Poetry-based projects.

Answer (score -5):

The short answer is add this to your `pyproject.toml` file (assuming you are using one since you are using `poetry`) and you should be good to go.

```
[flake8]
max-line-length = 88
extend-ignore = E203
```

This implies that the line length used by `flake8` is set to `88`, which is also the default used by black.

I would recommend that you take a look at the [Line Length section](https://github.com/psf/black#line-length) of Black's README. The above snippet is taken from there. Black's authors also explain the rationale behind the choice of the default value. They also detail alternative options to make `flake8` happy.

Comment: A plain `flake8` won't look into your `pyproject.toml` file. Put it into `.flake8` instead.

Comment: or put it in `setup.cfg`